# How do I reference a Blazor WASM project to another Blazor WASM?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, micro-frontend, asp.net-blazor

I want Create micro-frontends with Blazor WASM ([base on this article](https://dev.to/xanderselorm/introduction-to-micro-frontends-using-net-blazor-wasm-part-1-lc9)), I Create two blazor wasm project
one name is ***MicroFrontendsExample.Shell*** is container/appshell and other name is:***MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component***

I encountered this error when I referenced the ***MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component*** project to the ***MicroFrontendsExample.Shell***

error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Conflicting assets with the same target path
> '_framework/blazor.boot.json'. For assets 'Identity:
> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\repos\MicroFrontendsExample\MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot_framework\blazor.boot.json,
> SourceType: Project, SourceId: MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component,
> ContentRoot:
> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\repos\MicroFrontendsExample\MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot,
> BasePath: /, RelativePath: _framework/blazor.boot.json, AssetKind:
> Build, AssetMode: All, AssetRole: Primary, RelatedAsset: ,
> AssetTraitName: BlazorWebAssemblyResource, AssetTraitValue: manifest,
> CopyToOutputDirectory: PreserveNewest, CopyToPublishDirectory: Never,
> OriginalItemSpec: obj\Debug\net7.0\blazor.boot.json' and 'Identity:
> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\repos\MicroFrontendsExample\MicroFrontendsExample.Shell\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot_framework\blazor.boot.json,
> SourceType: Computed, SourceId: MicroFrontendsExample.Shell,
> ContentRoot:
> C:\Users\Sibetalaee\source\repos\MicroFrontendsExample\MicroFrontendsExample.Shell\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot,
> BasePath: /, RelativePath: _framework/blazor.boot.json, AssetKind:
> Build, AssetMode: All, AssetRole: Primary, RelatedAsset: ,
> AssetTraitName: BlazorWebAssemblyResource, AssetTraitValue: manifest,
> CopyToOutputDirectory: PreserveNewest, CopyToPublishDirectory: Never,
> OriginalItemSpec: obj\Debug\net7.0\blazor.boot.json' from different
> projects. MicroFrontendsExample.Shell C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets 391

I have no idea, how can I reference blazor wasm to another ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `StaticWebAssetBasePath` with different name for each project to distinguish.

In the `MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component` app's project file (`MicroFrontendsExample.B1Component.csproj`), add a `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>` property to a `<PropertyGroup>` with a value of `FirstApp` to set the base path for the project's static assets:

```
<StaticWebAssetBasePath>FirstApp</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
```

In the `MicroFrontendsExample.Shell` app's project file (`MicroFrontendsExample.Shell.csproj`), add a `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>` property to a `<PropertyGroup>` with a value of `SecondApp`:

```
<StaticWebAssetBasePath>SecondApp</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
```

**Note:** The name of `FirstApp` and `SecondApp` are merely for demonstration purposes.Any base path segments that distinguish the client apps are acceptable.